# How to copy a row from a 2d array to another

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hi I have a large 2D array (`sample[1000][10]`). I was wondering, how can I copy over the last row (1000) into a temp 2d array (`temp[1][10]`)?

EDIT: I have tried the following but I was wondering if there is a much quicker code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
temp[0][i] = sample[sample.length - 1][i];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `System.arraycopy`:

```
System.arraycopy(sample[999], 0, temp[0], 0, 10);
```